# Script para passar uma propaganda antes do vídeo

Tags: script, vídeo, youtube

Como faço para por uma propaganda minha particular antes de um vídeo do youtube e depois que passar 50% do tempo para o vídeo e passa outra propaganda depois continua o vídeo.

A propaganda seria um vídeo meu que entraria no lugar do principal por alguns momentos.

Queria que fosse mais ou menos como o youtube trabalha.

Estou usando de modo incorporado no meu site.

Comment: "_passar 50% do tempo para o vídeo e passa outra propaganda depois continua o vídeo_"... tendi nada..rs :)

Comment: Sim, exemplo, o vídeo tem 3 minutos. Antes de iniciar o vídeo aparece uma propaganda, começa a rolar o vídeo, quando der 1:30 do vídeo, da uma pausa, passa a propaganda, acabado a propaganda continua o vídeo até completar os 3 minutos.

Comment: Se vc quer passar um vídeo seu antes do Youtube, vc pode rodar ele antes e colocar um temporizador. Quando o temporizador terminar vc disponibiliza um botão tipo "Pular" que ao ser clicado irá carregar o vídeo do Youtube no lugar.

Comment: Entendi. É possível fazer isso, mas tem que usar API pra saber o quanto de vídeo já rodou. Quem tem intimidade com a API do Youtube poderá ajudar.

Comment: Então alguém se habilita a me ajudar com essa questão. Estou fazendo um projeto e acabei parando nisso.

Comment: Os seus vídeos de propaganda são do Youtube tb?

Comment: Se seu vídeos forem maior que 10 min, pode ser que isso o ajude. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6175006?hl=en

Comment: Os vídeos são do youtube, as propagandas não, ficaram hospedadas no portal.

Comment: Valdeir Psr, olhei o que falou mais não ajudou, Os vídeos são pequenos até 6 minutos máximo.

Comment: Os vídeos são seus e não monetizados ou de outros canais e já com preroll e placements?

Comment: Os vídeos são meus, as propagandas serão de pessoas que me ajudam. Quero retribui-los também.